# How the Unix user level is affecting my visibility to docker images?

Tags: linux, docker, unix

I am very new to Unix/docker,
I have the following two outputs on the console,

`admin@ansible:~/nachiket/workspace/docker-nachi-sample-app$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
admin@ansible:~/nachiket/workspace/docker-nachi-sample-app$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nachiketjoshi/python-log-generator   latest              ca675b7439ab        About an hour ago   908MB
python                               2.7                 4ee4ea2f0113        3 weeks ago         908MB`

can someone explain how the Unix user level is affecting my visibility to docker images...

Comment: Have you set up your non-root user to access docker?  See https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-systemd-unit-file and note that anyone with docker access can easily root the host.

Comment: Vague guess: you have `$DOCKER_HOST` set when you're not using sudo, and if you `sudo -E` you also won't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is because

> The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user.

So, after installing docker to have the same access level on another user instead of root you need to perform:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then verify if it worked on docker uses:

```
docker run hello-world
```

If everything goes right try to execute docker images and see if it has the same access level, I've tested on CentOS and it worked

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: I have already done this. This is exactly why I can see two level of visibility which I do not want. If my docker user/group has sudo access to Linux then why am I able to see a different result for the above two commands.